Extract XML, with children in separate tags
I have a scenario like,
I have Department and Emplyee table as in pic,
I have to join these 2 tables and generate the XML file with all Dept ID's and under each Dept ID, it should list all its employees in individual tags.
Result should look like this
<root>
<Dept>
  <DeptID>10</DeptID>
  <DeptName>Research</DeptName>
  <EMP><ID>100</ID></EMP>
  <EMP><ID>200</ID></EMP>
</Dept>

<Dept>
  <DeptID>20</DeptID>
  <DeptName>Finance</DeptName>
  <EMP><ID>300</ID></EMP>
  <EMP><ID>400</ID></EMP>
  <EMP><ID>500</ID></EMP>
  <EMP><ID>600</ID></EMP>
</Dept>
</root>

How would I achieve this ? Under each dept tag, all its employees should be listed as individual tags.
SELECT 
    D.DeptID,
    D.DeptName,
    -- ** How would I get the EMP details here? **
FROM Department D, Employee E
WHERE Department.DeptID = Employee.DeptID
FOR XML PATH('Dept'), ROOT('root')

Table Details

Please don't use images. Use table markdown.

FYI, using comma joins is not best practice, you should be using an explicit (inner) join.

Thanks Dale, will there be any data inconsistent in any of the scenarios if we go with comma join instead of explicit inner join ?

See the comment on the answer below. If done properly they do return the expected data, but easier to get wrong and are discouraged

Looks like you just need a nested FOR XML subquery.
SELECT 
    D.DeptID,
    D.DeptName,
    (
        SELECT
          E.ID
        FROM Employee E
        WHERE D.DeptID = E.DeptID
        FOR XML PATH('EMP'), TYPE
    )
FROM Department D
FOR XML PATH('Dept'), ROOT('root'), TYPE;

Note that comma-joins are really old-style and difficult to read, they should be avoided.

I don't get that https://dbfiddle.uk/DWLzrire you'd need to show what you are actually doing because that shouldn't happen.
